# ¿Por qué no se ejecuta el controlador 2?

Tags: angularjs

En Angular.js, ¿por qué no me funciona el controlador número dos en la misma página?

Ya revisé el código. Me trae la información de la base de datos y al momento que quiero mostrar los registros solamente ejecuta el controlador 1.

¿Qué podrá ser?

Controlador 1:

```
<div ng-controller="Crt1">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        .........
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controlador 2:

```
<div ng-controller="Crt2">

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        ........
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dicho esto, nuestras dotes adivinatorias son reducidas. Sin el código no podremos saber qué te ocurre.

Comment: Por la falta de atención que recibe la pregunta por parte de su autor, voto su cierre con el motivo "necesita más detalles y aclaraciones".

Comment: Perdón pero si puedo enviar algo porque intente subir el código y el sitio no me dejo poner varias lineas de codigo, tuve que quitar unas lineas y el sitio me publico eso que aparece alli.

Comment: Debes editar tu pregunta y seleccionar el texto que es código fuente y pulsar el botón `{}` para que ponga el formato adecuado. También puedes hacerlo tú mismo agregando tres comillas invertidas antes y después del código (voy a editar tu pregunta para que veas un ejemplo).